# How to stop opening the same record in a new window more than once in QTableView?

Tags: qt, qtableview

I need some help, I have a QTableView where I'm displaying list of records, to display further details of any record I'm opening a new window by clicking on the record,
all well apart from that I can open the SAME record more than once, How can I prevent this happening ?

this is what I have so far

```
while(qry.next())
    {
        QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
        model->setQuery(qry);
    }
    connect(ui->tableView_visitLog, SIGNAL(pressed(const QModelIndex&)),this,
            SLOT(on_tableView_visitorLog_clicked(const QModelIndex&)));


 void ControlPanel::on_tableView_visitorLog_clicked(const QModelIndex& index)
 {
    const QAbstractItemModel* tableModel = ui->tableView_visitLog->model();
    int id = tableModel->data(tableModel->index(index.row(),0),Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();
    visitordetails = new VisitorDetails(id, this);
    visitordetails->show();
 }
```